# Conditional to check if a user has chosen a modifer - Exp:resso Store

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a conditional to check if a modifier has been chosen? I am trying to create a notification to inform the user the need to choose a modifier before trying to add the product to their cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a variable you can use in a conditional.

But this would be easy to accomplish with jQuery. When the Add To Cart button is clicked, first check to see if a modifier is selected... if one isn't selected you can Alert your message so show an error on the page as needed.

Comment: Thanks Anna, was hoping there would be a simple conditional i could use... not much of a jquery/javascript programmer :(.

Comment: If a variable isn't mentioned in the docs, I'd say a conditional isn't doable. This is very easy to do with jQuery... no time like the present to start learning it. It's invaluable as a web dev to have it as a tool. Post a screenshot of your page and the relevant html somewhere and I can help point the way.

Comment: Let's use http://jsfiddle.net to get it working... Post your html there please for the modifier dropdown and the add to cart button... and post a screenshot or a link to the actual page.

Comment: Hello Anna, Thanks for taking the time out to help :). Here is the JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tcherokee/TdhkS/1/)

Comment: Here is a working version that shows a JS alert. This will get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/TdhkS/3/

Comment: Hello Anna, Thanks for your help. Your script worked well as a base... after some reading and researching, I have updated it a bit since having explicitly defined ids won't have worked across all pages. here is what i currently have... seems to work [http://jsfiddle.net/tcherokee/TdhkS/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/tcherokee/TdhkS/4/)

Comment: Perfect. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help. I'm using something similar to grab the value of a selected modifier. It checks for a modifier value. While I haven't tested it, it should return whatever message you want if no modifier_value is found.

```
{exp:store:checkout}
{items}
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  {modifiers}
    {if "{modifier_value}" == ""}
    Message or code that you want the user to see.
    {/if}
  {/modifiers}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Hope that helps.